flutter app fire base firestore database configuration error for run time app
Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putObject(Ljava/lang/Object;JLjava/lang/Object;)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
2
: Accessing hidden method Lsun/misc/Unsafe;->putLong(Ljava/lang/Object;JJ)V (greylist, linking, allowed)
this is error for print in my log. but app is working. but this error show the any time for my log.
Andorid -> app -> src -> debug -> AndroidManifest.xml allow this permission but is not fine.
